# How to run Django app from docker containers with rabbitmq

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq

I have a django app which I want to run it locally and see the changes that I make simultaneously on the localhost rather that deploying it every time to the production server. My previous developers have put these on read me, I tried these steps but not able to launch it locally.

```
docker run --rm --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 - v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres:9.6.2
docker run --name redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis
docker run --rm -d --hostname my-rabbit --name rabbitmq -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 4369:4369 -p 25672:25672 rabbitmq:3
docker exec -it rabbitmq bash
rabbitmqctl add_user wee wee
rabbitmqctl add_vhost wee
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p wee wee ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do development when relying on several other services is to use docker-compose to bring everything up and have it be interconnected. For example what you are using right now is equivalent to the following

```
version: '3.5'

volumes:
  pgdata:
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: "postgres"
    image: postgres:9.6.2
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
  redis:
    container_name: "redis"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    image: rabbitmq:3
    hostname: my-rabbit
    ports:
      - "5671:5671"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "4369:4369"
      - "25672:25672"
```

I would then define another service for your django application but it may be enough that you have all of those available for django to access on local host. If you were to define another service it could look something like the following.
    django:
      container_name: "django_app"
      image: python:latest
      volumes:
        - "./path-to-your-application/:/path-to-where-your-code-will-run/:rw
      depends_on:
        - postgres
        - rabbit_mq
        - reddis
      environment:
        SOME_SETTING: "its value"

The benefit to using docker compose is that you can bring up the entire application at once with `docker-compose up -d`. Also you dont have to worry about networking since all of it will come up in one network.